# Convert List<Map<Long, String>> to List<Long> Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Maps, in which each of the maps has only `one key-value pair` each. I need to convert this to just a list of the  keys. I am trying to use streams as follows:

```
List<Map<Long, String>> lst = // some data
List<Long> successList = lst.stream().map(ele -> ele.keySet().toArray()[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I end up getting the following error:

```
java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
  equality constraints: java.lang.Long
  lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

How do I resolve this issue or is there any better approach?

Comment: A tip I find useful for solving type inference errors in an IDE: extract a variable. This gets the IDE to attempt to infer the type: in this case, `successList` is actually something like `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Stream#flatMap` like below:

```
lst.stream()
   .flatMap(e->e.entrySet().stream())
   .map(e->e.getKey())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit:**  (As per comment) More elegant way will be a use of `Map#keySet` instead of  `Map#entrySet`.

```
lst.stream()
   .flatMap(e -> e.keySet().stream())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While in this case it's a matter of taste, I think `Map.Entry::getKey` is more verbose than `e -> e.getKey()` and it provides more context. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Why not simply `flatMap(e->e.keySet().stream())`?

Answer (score 5):

You need Just :

```
List<Long> successList = lst.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Although better answers have been posted already (`flatMap` is your friend here), I think it's worth pointing out here that the typing error stems from the use of `toArray` without an argument.

```
jshell> List<Long> a = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
a ==> [1, 2, 3, 4]

jshell> a.toArray()
$2 ==> Object[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

See there? When you use `toArray` without an argument, you get a result of type `Object[]`. So do this instead:

```
jshell> a.toArray(new Long[1])
$3 ==> Long[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

By adding the argument `new Long[1]` we force the result of `toArray` to be an array of Longs, which you want, instead of an array of objects.

See the [JavaDoc for `toArray'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Comment: We can also use `new Long[1]` if we are sure that there will be only one element. This way passed array will be used instead of creating new array with proper size.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
lst.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(toList());
```